# How to get the username from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The name of the question might not be the most appropriate so I'm going to try and explain my problem as good as I can:

I'm computing the **cosine similarity between users** depending on their purchase history, so I've got a matrix like this:

```
product    63767    76863    84325    86217    86833    130365   537077   
username                                                                                           
45michael      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      1.0      1.0      0.0      
7762hc         0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      
adrian12       0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0     
alicia7        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0
```

Where 1 indicates if the user has bought the book and 0 if the didn't.

After getting that matrix I've computed the cosine similarity matrix between users:

```
cosine_sim = pd.DataFrame(cosine_sim, ndex=df_matrix.index, `columns = df_matrix.index)
```

And the resultant matrix looks like this:

```
username   45michael  7762hc  adrian12   alicia7 
username                                                                                           
45michael   1.000000     0.0       0.0  0.577350     
7762hc      0.000000     0.0       0.0  0.000000     
adrian12    0.000000     0.0       0.0  0.000000    
alicia7     0.577350     0.0       0.0  1.000000
```

So now if I want to get the **most similar users** to, for example, 45michael I just have to do this:

```
cosine_sim['45michael'].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:11]
```

Which returns an output like this:

```
username
alicia7     0.577350
adrian12    0.000000
7762hc      0.000000
```

And now I want to iterate over that usernames in the original df but when I do this:

```
for username in similar_users:
...     print(username)
```

It returns me this:

```
0.5773502691896258
0.0
0.0
```

When what I was expecting was:

```
alicia7     
adrian12    
7762hc
```

Does someone know how to get the username instead of the cosine similarity value?

Comment: try print(username.index.values)

Comment: your output is a series? cant u use dataframe.index?

Comment: Oh my god, how did I not think of that T.T